# Tippy nested tooltip - bad positioning

Tags: html, css, tippyjs

I have a button with a tippy tooltip, this button opens tippy dropdown and each button within this dropdown has a separate tooltip. the problem is that this last tooltip (for each dropdown item) is bad positioned. Have a look at the below pictures:

First tooltip - OK

[image]

Dropdown - OK

[image]

Dropdown item tooltip - BAD

[image]

I can't share quickly a code so maybe based on this information you can say where the problem might be? Styling?

Comment: Without code, how are we supposed to say "where" the problem might be? Also, asking for opinions makes it off-topic.

Comment: I solved it by adding appendTo: () => document.body but I'm wondering why does it help